# Google Chrome sometimes loses its pinned tabs?

Tags: google-chrome, troubleshooting, pinning

In some occasions; for instance, when I don't leave the browser open long enough and close it again; then upon reopening the browser lost all my pinned tabs. Does anyone know why this happens and what I could do about it? Using favorites to reopen them is an option, but I find it tedious to have to repin them.

How can I tell my browser that **these are my pinned sites; so, please don't mess with them**?

Comment: I'm experiencing this lesser these days, but will let it open for others that have the problem.

Comment: Highly active question, I will need 10 more reputation, but I can tell you that, just go to history - as all pinned tabs get loaded at the very beginning, they will be at first of any session, so click on those links, pin them again..

Comment: I think this happens when you have multiple windows open. The tabs are only open on the one window. Chrome reopens only the last window that you closed. So when you close the window with the pinned tabs, and then close the other window, your tabs are gone..

Comment: @GolezTrol True but there is the .../Exit menu which closes all windows at once. Chrome [usually] reopens with all windows and all pinned tabs.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

When you open the browser, try pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>. This will open old tabs, and I believe it will restore your pinned tabs. [Others still seem to have this problem as well.](https://productforums.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/chrome/PlMI2fl3Ivk)

Comment: Note: "Others **still** seem to have this problem as well" is from over a year ago, so is this question.

Comment: @Alex I'm aware. However, I'm still having this problem today, and the StackExchange sites function as a QA archive, not a forum. Thus, posting a relevant answer to a question is still valid no matter how old it is.

Comment: I see, I was just pointing out what I thought was an old issue - since you didn't say you were still facing it, it seemed to me that this was only an issue in a 1 year old version of the software. I myself have answered old questions that were no longer an issue because someone bumped it for no reason, but since you're still facing this problem I guess it's recent. Cheers.

Comment: This only works if the windows with the pinned tabs was the last open chrome window.

Comment: @markus If you press `CTRL` + `SHIFT` + `T` a second time in the window that opens, it should work open the window that you closed before the last one.

Comment: Works for Edge too.

Answer (score 6):

I got a solution.

1. just click on 3 dots at top right side.
2. move your cursor over history.
3. It will now show you the no. of tabs that were pinned. In my case there were 10 so It showed in history "10 tabs" . I clicked on it and it re-opened my all the 10 tabs that I pinned earlier.

Comment: getting lose pinned tabs from history worked for me, thank you.

Comment: Thank you very much. Nevertheless, why does this (losing of pinned tabs) happen at all? Bug or feature?

Answer (score 3):

This happened to me once too often.

My solution is fairly simple -

1. Create a new folder in Bookmarks Bar and name it "**Pinned**".
2. Bookmark all pinned tabs into this folder.
3. Install the [Pin all tabs](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pin-all-tabs/ggdflfnbccnnmnejiblifjjgeiepdjop) extension by James Fairbairn from the web store.
   `Note: Extension was last updated: 22 December 2014, Size: 4.32KiB`
4. When I lose everything, including pinned tabs, right click on the "**Pinned**" folder in Bookmarks bar and select the "**Open all bookmarks in new window**" option. This will open all the pinned tabs you previously bookmarked, in the same order as before.
5. Click on the `Pin all tabs` extension and all the tabs are restored as before.

Answer (score -2):

Right click on top bar where pinned tabs kept and click 'restore'.Works for me.

Comment: That's a ridiculous answer. That "Restore" is a Windows option that restores the window to its original dimensions and position.

Comment: Maybe he meant "Reopen closed tabs"